# Degree of deck transformations $S^n \rightarrow S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'd like some verification for the following two claims [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~gyueun.lee/writing/qual_sols.pdf) on page four (b) and (c). That is, if we first suppose $S^{2n}$ covers $X$, then if $d:S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n}$ is a nontrivial deck transformation we know that $deg(d) = (-1)^{2n+1}$.

Similarly if $S^{2n+1}$ covers $X$ then nontrivial deck transformations have $deg(d) = (-1)^{2n+2}$.

Here's what I've tried thinking about. In my book (Bredon), we define the degree of a map $d:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ to be the number $a$ such that $d_*(\gamma) = a \gamma$ for all $\gamma \in \tilde{H}_n(S^n) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$. This question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997357/possible-degree-of-a-cover-p-colon-s2n-to-x) showed me that only $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts freely on $S^{2n}$. I don't know why that is, but assuming it is true this means that the action is like the antipodal identification giving us projective space, which I have shown before has degree $-1$ when doing problem related to the Hairy Ball Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Deck transformations of connected covers are determined by their value on one point which means nonidentity transformations have no fixed points. Any map $S^n \rightarrow S^n$ with no fixed points is homotopic to the antipodal map which makes its degree $-1^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please explain why a continuous map of spheres with no FPs is homotopic to the antipodal map? I understand that by Hopf degree theorem, same degree implies homotopic.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142264/what-is-the-degree-of-f-sn-to-sn-when-f-has-no-fixed-points

Comment: Your question is actually the result I would use to prove the theorem about free actions on even spheres. It is really simple if you know some things about degrees.